# Spring Data MongoDB: Parameter marked with @Indexed not wirtten in DB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have some trouble with my first spring backend for a Mongo DB. I have created a component class with some attributes. One of them is a part number which shall be unique. SO I set the @Indexed (unique = true) annotation.

The application is working fine. But if I test the endpoint with postman all attributes are written to the Mongo Document except the part number. PN is allways empyt. I dont understand why. I would be glad if someone can help me with his issuse.

This is the component class

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Document
public class Component {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String cType;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String pN;
    private String name;
    private double diameter;
    private double bendradius;
    private double maxLenght;
    private String modelPath;
    private String description;
    private String normOrStandard;
}
```

This is an example post request to the route http://localhost:8080/components

```
    {

        "PN":"13245"
    }
```

And the result:

```
{
    "id": "61c9c23960435c3c0c4d5844",
    "name": null,
    "diameter": 0.0,
    "bendradius": 0.0,
    "maxLenght": 0.0,
    "modelPath": null,
    "description": null,
    "normOrStandard": null,
    "ctype": null,
    "pn": null,
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/components/61c9c23960435c3c0c4d5844"
        },
        "components": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/components"
        }
    }
}
```

This also happens if all fields are filled.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your Postman request with case sensitive HTTP parameters matching to the fields in the Component class:

```
{
   "pN":"13245"
}
```

Instead of:

```
{
   "PN":"13245"
}
```

Comment: Wow, great tipp. It worked. It was case sensitive. The solutions was not "pN":"13245" but everything with small letters (pn :)